# Is it true that $A\subset f^{-1}(f(A))$ if and only if $f$ is injective?

Tags: analysis, elementary-set-theory

I'm doing some homework and I have trouble with some problems.
Let $X,Y$ be sets, $f:X\mapsto Y$, $A \subset X$, $C\subset Y$.
I need to prove that $A\subset f^{-1}(f(A))$ if and only if $f$ is injective; and that $f(f^{-1}(C))\subset C$ if and only if $f$ is surjective. 
I tried to apply the definitions but I just got confused because of $f^{-1}(f(A))$, so i could use some advice.

Comment: It is not enough that $A \subset f^{-1}(f(A))$ for some $A \subset X$, because let $f: \{1, 2, 3\} \rightarrow \{1, 2\}$ with $f(1) = 1$, $f(2) = f(3) = 2$ and $A = \{1\}$ then $A \subset f^{-1}(f(A))$ but f is not injective.

Comment: These properties are not true as stated. Are you sure this is what your homework says?

Comment: @ArnaudD I'm not sure. That's how I have the exercises in the copy my teacher gave me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $f^{-1}(f(C))$ should be $f(f^{-1}(C))$.

---

The inclusion $A\subset f^{-1}(f(A))$ is true for every map and every subset of the map's domain.

Indeed, if $a\in A$, then $f(a)\in f(A)$ (by definition), which is to say that $a\in f^{-1}(f(A))$.

Similarly, $f(f^{-1}(C))\subset C$ holds for every map $f$ and every subset of the map's codomain. Indeed, if $y\in f(f^{-1}(C))$, then $y=f(x)$, for some $x\in f^{-1}(C)$. But then $f(x)\in C$, which is to say $y\in C$.

What you want to show is that

> $f\colon X\to Y$ is injective if and only if, for every $A\subset X$, $A=f^{-1}(f(A))$

and similarly that

> $f\colon X\to Y$ is surjective if and only if, for every $C\subset Y$, $C=f(f^{-1}(C))$

Hint for the $\Rightarrow$ direction in the first statement: you have to prove that $f^{-1}(f(A))\subset A$. Take $x\in f^{-1}(f(A))$; then $f(x)\in f(A)$. Apply injectivity.

Comment: I made the correction. The same hint holds for the surjectivity proposition?

Comment: @ArmandoRosas Very similar. Don't forget to prove also the $\Leftarrow$ directions.

Comment: I have trouble with the $\Leftarrow$ proof of surjectivity. I let c be in C , then c it's an element of $f(f^{-1}(C))$, can i directly say that f is surjective here? Because then $c=f(x)$ with $x\in f^{-1}(C)\subset X$, is it not?

Comment: @ArmandoRosas For $C=Y$, $Y=f(f^{-1}(Y))=f(X)$.

Comment: When you say "if $a∈A$, then $f(a)∈f(A)$ (by definition)" do you mean definition of inverse function?

Comment: @Omar By definition of $f(A)$

Comment: ok that makes sense.